# How to horizontally center an absolutely positioned div over its relatively positioned parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a speech-bubble class that has a dynamic size and is absolutely positioned.  I want it to always be *horizontally* centered over its parent element which is relatively positioned, no matter what the speech-bubble's size is.  I want it to look something like this (where the letter 'O' is the parent relatively positioned element):

[image]

Currently, it looks like this if I set the `left` attribute to 0:

[image]

This is an easy problem to solve if I can guarantee that the size of the bubble is fixed, but it is most definitely not.  I can't solve this by setting `width` or `left` or `margin-left` on an element with class`bubble`.  It needs to be more robust than that.

I would prefer a css solution if there is one.  However, if the only solution is a javascript one, I will consider that as well.

This is what the code looks like.  Note that the margins on smart-bubble-wrapper are not really needed, they only exist so that you can see the bubble in the code sample:

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.bubble {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #bababf;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6bcded;
  left: 0;
  color: #333333;
}

.bubble-bottom {
  bottom: 30px;
}

.bubble-middle-after {
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.bubble-middle-before {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.bubble-bottom-before {
  bottom: -8px;
}

.bubble-bottom-after {
  bottom: -12px;
  border-width: 12px 12px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
}

.bubble-after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.bubble-before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bababf;
  border-width: 13px 13px 0;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6bcded;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  O
  <div class="bubble bubble-middle bubble-bottom" arrow-horizontal="middle" arrow-vertical="bottom">
    <div class="bubble-before bubble-middle-before bubble-bottom-before"></div>
    <span class="ng-scope">How do I center this bubble</span>
    <div class="bubble-after bubble-middle-after bubble-bottom-after"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

1. Choose a big enough length `x`
2. Set `left` to some negative value `-x`
3. Set `right` to `calc(100% - x)`
4. Assuming `x` is big enough, the absolutely positioned element will be centered at the left.
5. But its width will be `2*x`. Use `width: fit-content` or `width: max-content` to fix this.
6. But now it's over-constrained. Set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` to keep the centering.

For example, choosing `x = 100%`,

```css
left: -100%;
right: 0;
width: fit-content; /* may need vendor prefixes */
margin: 0 auto;
```

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.bubble {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #bababf;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6bcded;
  color: #333333;

  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content; /* may need vendor prefixes */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bubble-bottom {
  bottom: 30px;
}
.bubble-middle-after {
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}
.bubble-middle-before {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.bubble-bottom-before {
  bottom: -8px;
}
.bubble-bottom-after {
  bottom: -12px;
  border-width: 12px 12px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
}
.bubble-after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.bubble-before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bababf;
  border-width: 13px 13px 0;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6bcded;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  O
  <div class="bubble bubble-middle bubble-bottom" arrow-horizontal="middle" arrow-vertical="bottom">
    <div class="bubble-before bubble-middle-before bubble-bottom-before"></div>
    <span class="ng-scope">How do I center this bubble</span>
    <div class="bubble-after bubble-middle-after bubble-bottom-after"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For browsers that don't support `width: fit-content`, you can add an inline-block inner wrapper, which can be centered with `text-align: center`.

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.bubble {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bubble-inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #bababf;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6bcded;
  color: #333333;
}
.bubble-bottom {
  bottom: 30px;
}
.bubble-middle-after {
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}
.bubble-middle-before {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.bubble-bottom-before {
  bottom: -8px;
}
.bubble-bottom-after {
  bottom: -12px;
  border-width: 12px 12px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
}
.bubble-after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.bubble-before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bababf;
  border-width: 13px 13px 0;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6bcded;
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  O
  <div class="bubble bubble-middle bubble-bottom" arrow-horizontal="middle" arrow-vertical="bottom">
    <div class="bubble-inner-wrapper">
      <div class="bubble-before bubble-middle-before bubble-bottom-before"></div>
      <span class="ng-scope">How do I center this bubble</span>
      <div class="bubble-after bubble-middle-after bubble-bottom-after"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never would've thought to do it that way.  Brilliant!

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE:** [Values of 0 shouldn't have units specified.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units)

You could also re-position your bubble absolutely.

```
.bubble-bottom-after:before { 
  content: 'O';
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
}
```

---

```css
.smart-bubble-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.bubble-bottom-after:before { 
  content: 'O';
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
}

.bubble {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #bababf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #6bcded;
  left: -105px;
  color: #333;
}

.bubble-bottom {
  bottom: 30px;
}

.bubble-middle-after {
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.bubble-middle-before {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.bubble-bottom-before {
  bottom: -8px;
}

.bubble-bottom-after {
  bottom: -12px;
  border-width: 12px 12px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFF transparent;
}

.bubble-after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.bubble-before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #bababf;
  border-width: 13px 13px 0;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #6bcded;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="smart-bubble-wrapper">
  <div class="bubble bubble-middle bubble-bottom" arrow-horizontal="middle" arrow-vertical="bottom">
    <div class="bubble-before bubble-middle-before bubble-bottom-before"></div>
    <span class="ng-scope">How do I center this bubble</span>
    <div class="bubble-after bubble-middle-after bubble-bottom-after"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this solution won't work since if the speech bubble increases in width, the bubble won't center over the 'O'.  I need it to always center over the 'O' no matter what the width of the speech bubble is.

Comment: Then re-position your bubble absolutely.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means.  Would you explain how to re-position the bubble absolutely?

Comment: By using CSS [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top), [left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) on the bubble class. I don't know of another way in pure CSS without a pseudo selector.

Comment: The spec says "*After a zero length, the unit identifier is optional*". This means it *may* not be there, it doesn't meant it *should* not be there.